# Why might re.search process these patterns differently?

Tags: regular-expression, python

I regularly use [sagetex](https://github.com/sagemath/sagetex), which is written in python.

One of the scripts in the package defines a variable like this:

```
ignore = r"^( _st_.goboom|print 'SageT| ?_st_.current_tex_line)"
```

The script then uses `re.find` as follows:

```
re.search(ignore, line)
```

Recently, in effort to prepare for a switch to python 3, the `ignore` variable was changed to

```
ignore = r"^( _st_.goboom|print('SageT| ?_st_.current_tex_line))"
```

For some reason, this change causes my problems on some of my documents.

My question is: is there any difference between these two definitions of the `ignore` variable if it is to be used in `re.search`?

Obviously it would be useful if I could post why this is causing a problem for me, but the script is somewhat long and the project I'm using the script on is very long.

In short: the script returns the correct result with the first definition of `ignore` and the script always returns `False` with the second definition of `ignore`.

I'm hoping there is an obvious reason that these two definitions of `ignore` result in different behavior.

Comment: Well, what are you searching? Could you be searching python2 documents that simply don't have the`print('foo')` pattern since python 2 would have `print 'foo'`? Could you also clarify why you are asking here instead of on [so] (if this is a pure python issue) or on [tex.se] (if this is a TeX one)? Why is this related to *nix?

Comment: @terdon It's never been clear to me what belongs here and what belongs on Stack Overflow. I tried to ask the question in such a way that I hoped it could be reduced to a scripting issue. Apologies for the spam.

Comment: Scripting is on topic here, but it tends to be "sysadminish" scripting. Some questions abouts scripting/scripting languages are obviously on topic here, others are obviously not on topic. Yours is very much in the middle, so no worries, it isn't completely clear to me either :). However, since the answer makes it clear it is indeed a regex issue, that pushes it more onto the on topic side since we absolutely do regexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The updated regex lacks a space that the prior regex had.

```
ignore = r"^( _st_.goboom|print 'SageT| ?_st_.current_tex_line)"
ignore = r"^( _st_.goboom|print('SageT| ?_st_.current_tex_line))"
```

I think what was wanted was simply

```
ignore = r"^( _st_.goboom|print ('SageT| ?_st_.current_tex_line))"
```

As far as the explanation... normally, spaces in regexes are literal characters.

Now, I'll admit, it could be the change in and of itself.  You went from saying that you were going to ignore

```
" _st_.goboom"
"print 'SageT"
"_st.current_tex_line"
" _st.current_tex_line"
```

to ignoring

```
" _st_.goboom"
"print 'SageT"
"print '_st.current_tex_line"
"print ' _st.current_tex_line"
```

(Note: all of the '.' characters in the regex also match any character, but I don't want to have 258 * 6 lines or so lines of explaining exactly what patterns were being ignored.)

Comment: This works! Would never have seen this myself.